# importing ontologies in owlready

Tags: python, owlready

I did some code in owl ready and now I need to import an Ontology to use it. The problem is owlready doesn't do it correctly, no classes found. Like if I try to import go.owl (http://geneontology.org/docs/download-ontology/) and then add a class (for simplicity)
named `A` with code:

```
with onto:
  class A(GO_0046852):
    pass
```

I get the error

> NameError: name 'GO_0000030' is not defined

This is because owlready takes into consideration thats the class IRI should be `#GO_0000030` not `http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0046852` or even `http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo#GO_0046852`
which doesn't make sense. So no class gets detected. How can I fix this, or go around it?

I can't swap to another API now because I already did so much code.
This is the code that yields an error:

```
from owlready2 import *

onto = get_ontology("go.owl").load()
with onto:
    class A(GO_0000030):
        pass
onto.save(file = "test.owl", format = "rdfxml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the class *'GO_0046852'* in the original ontology?

From the example of OWLREADY, the definition is

```
with onto:
   class Drug(Thing):
      pass
```

Here, **Thing** is already a defined class in the ontology, so class **Drug** inherits all the properties of class **Thing**. Therefore, whatever class you write inside bracket should be declared in the ontology. That is the reason you are getting the error.

Please refer to Namespace section in owlready2.0 documentation.

You have to call a namespace, after loading the ontology from the storage.

```
obo = get_namespace("http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/")
print(obo.GO_0000001)
```

Therefore, when you pass obo.GO_0000001 should give you the output.